# How to display the image after clicking from list?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am thinking of trying to supply an API url to my html.

My idea is to redirect the page to my html page where the image displayed is the one clicked from the list from other html.

I am having a hard time since I am not sure where to look and I dont see any examples same as what I wanted.

What I want to do:
The image list would be displayed from an index html page then when item is clicked, be redirected to my html page.

All I have tried is to upload the images from my computer but that is not what I wanted.

The part where the image should be displayed is just plain text for now.

```html
<div id="page_getting_started" class="display_area_content display_none narrow_page_content">
          <p>A more detailed user guide (with screenshots and descriptions) is <a href="http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/docs/user_guide.html">available here</a>.</p>
          <ol>
            <li><strong>Load Images</strong>: The first step is to load all the images that you wish to annotate. There are multiple ways to add images to a VIA project. Choose the method that suits your use case.
              <ul>
                <li>Method 1: Selecting local files using browser's file selector
                  <ol>
                    <li>Click <span class="text_button" title="Load or Add Images" onclick="sel_local_images()"><code>Project &rarr; Add local files</code></span></li>
                    <li>Select desired images and click <code>Open</code></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Method 2: Adding files from URL or absolute path
                  <ol>
                    <li>Click <span class="text_button" title="Add images from a web URL (e.g. http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/images/swan.jpg)" onclick="project_file_add_url_with_input()"><code>Project &rarr; Add files from URL</code></span></li>
                    <li>Enter URL and click <code>OK</code></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Method 3: Adding files from list of url or absolute path stored in text file
                  <ol>
                    <li>Create a text file containing URL and absolute path (one per line)</li>
                    <li>Click <span class="text_button" title="Add images from a list of web url or absolute path stored in a text file (one url or path per line)" onclick="sel_local_data_file('files_url')"><code>Project &rarr; Add url or path from text file</code></span></li>
                    <li>Select the text file and click <code>Open</code></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><strong>Draw Regions</strong>: Select a region shape (<span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('rect')">rectangle</span>, <span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('circle')">circle</span>, <span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('ellipse')">ellipse</span>, <span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('polygon')">polygon</span>, <span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('point')">point</span>, <span class="text_button" onclick="select_region_shape('polyline')">polyline</span>) from the left sidebar and draw regions as follows:

              <ul>
                <li>Rectangle, Circle and Ellipse
                  <ul>
                    <li>Press left mouse button, drag mouse cursor and release mouse button.</li>
                    <li>To define a point inside an existing region, click inside the region to select it (if not already selected), now press left mouse button, drag and release to draw region inside existing region.</li>
                    <li>To select, click inside the region. If the click point contains multiple regions, then clicking multiple times at that location shuffles selection through those regions.</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li>Point
                  <ul>
                    <li>Click to define points.</li>
                    <li>To draw a region inside existing region, click inside the region to select it (if not already selected), now click again to define the point.</li>
                    <li>To select, click on (or near) the existing point.</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li>Polygon and Polyline
                  <ul>
                    <li>Click to define vertices.</li>
                    <li>Press <strong>[Enter]</strong> to finish drawing the region or press [Esc] to cancel.</li>
                    <li>If the first vertex needs to be defined inside an existing region, click inside the region to select it (if not already selected), now click again to define the vertex.</li>
                    <li>To select, click inside the region. If the click point contains multiple regions, then clicking multiple times at that location shuffles selection through those regions.</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><strong>Create Annotations</strong>: For a more detailed description of this step, see <a href="http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/docs/creating_annotations.html">Creating Annotations : VIA User Guide</a>. Click the <span class="text_button" onclick="annotation_editor_toggle_all_regions_editor()"><code>View &rarr; Toggle attributes editor</code></span> to show attributes editor panel in left sidebar and add the desired file or region attributes (e.g. name). Now click <span class="text_button" onclick="annotation_editor_toggle_all_regions_editor()"><code>View &rarr; Toggle annotations editor</code></span> to show the annotation editor panel in the bottom side. Update the annotations for each region.</li>
            <li><strong>Export Annotations</strong>: To export the annotations in json or csv format, click <span class="text_button" onclick="download_all_region_data('csv')"><code>Annotation &rarr; Export annotations</code></span> in top menubar.</li>
            <li><strong>Save Project</strong>: To save the project, click <span class="text_button" onclick="project_save_with_confirm()"><code>Project &rarr; Save</code></span> in top menubar.</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
```

I expect to see the image in my html page when clicked from the list from another html.

Comment: You haven't used any Angular at all, this is just plain HTML with some JS events, if you are just beginning with Angular, I suggest you go through the docs (https://angular.io/docs) :)

Comment: Yes. I want to try it first with html to html before integrating to Angular